# C++ Generic Object Pointer

Tags: c++, class, pointers, object

I have recently been working on a C++ project that requires a system whereby classes can be stored in a map (a library). From my research, I have concluded that I need to use a pointer to an object of the class. That's fine, I have the object, however I need to make the pointer fit **multiple** different objects from different classes. If this is unclear, here is my code.

```
typedef NO-IDEA-WHAT-GOES-HERE;
struct library {
    std::map<std::string, objPointer> lib;
};
```

I need to know how to create a pointer that can accept an object from more than just one single class, i.e.

```
//NOT WHAT I WANT
module someMod;
library *objPointer;
objPointer = &someMod;
```

But something more like...

```
typedef POINTER; //Not sure what to put here
module someMod;
std::map<std::string, POINTER> lib;
lib["something"] = someMod;
otherModule someOtherMod;
lib["somethingelse"] = someOtherMod;
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What about void*, then use casting.

Comment: If you want to own the objects you are putting in the map, maybe `std::any`, but I find that there's usually a better solution

Comment: In C++ there is almost never a reason to use `void` pointers outside of interactions with other languages. If you need to store a variety of classes in a single container and they have no relationship what-so-ever that can be used to establish a common base class, odds are overwhelmingly good you're headed down a bad design path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> That's fine, I have the object, however I need to make the pointer fit multiple different objects from different classes.

This is a common pattern in many libraries and applications.

1. Create a namespace specific to your application.
2. Create an abstract class that can be used as the base class of all the important classes in your application.
3. Make sure that all the important classes are derived from the base class.

That will allow you to store pointers to instances of all the important classes in your application in whatever container you wish to store them.

Over time, you will find that you will be able to implement a lot of  functionality using just the base class interface.